# How can I receive result of factorial to another class?

Tags: java

The problem is to receive the result of previous calculations.

```
public class FactorialArray {

    public static long[] factorial = new long[21];
    public static int fact = 0;

    static {
        factorial[0] = 1;
    }

    public static long factorial(int x) {
        while (fact < x) {
            long element;
            factorial[fact] = element.getFact(element);
            fact++;
        }
        return factorial[x];
    }
```

And here it is a class where I calculated factorial:

```
public class Factorial {

    private long factorialCalculator(int x){
        if(x==0 || x==1)
            return 1;
        else 
            return  (long)x*factorialCalculator(x-1); 
    }

    public long getFact(int x){
        return factorialCalculator(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: `factorial[fact] = element.getFact(element)`??

Comment: i think you can do a another class and use a simple return method where you put the code that actually have in your main , then you wont need to declare any static

Comment: The methods return a value.  What is the issue?

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: it underlines element.getFact(element)

Comment: i changed to element.getFact(fact);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public static long [] factorial(int x) {
        Factorial factObj = new Factorial();

```
    while (fact < x) {
        long element;
        factorial[fact] = factObj.getFact(fact);
        fact++;
    }
    return factorial;
}

static class Factorial {

    private long factorialCalculator(int x) {
        if (x == 0 || x == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return (long) x * factorialCalculator(x - 1);
    }

    public long getFact(int x) {
        return factorialCalculator(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Returning factorial[x] that's why it is showing 0  ,we are calculating till x-1 . Instead print factorial array. And create array length with input value